# Change height with animate() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to accomplish a simple box selection and indicate which one is clicked.

```
$(".features").click(function(){
    $(".pBox").css("border-color","#ccc");
    $(this).parent().parent().css("border-color","#cc0000");
    $(this).parent().parent().animate({
        height: "20%"
    });
});
```

Also I would like to increase the height of the box by 10%, unfortunately, while the color of selected box changes, I have no luck with changing the height. If I change the width, it works fine... What am I missing?

Comment: Where is your HTML?  How about a live demo in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/LfCNp/

Comment: Setting a percent height will only work if the node's parent has a defined height.  If it doesn't his code would do nothing.  Even a slight change to your example can break it: http://jsfiddle.net/LfCNp/1/  We really need more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".features").click(function(){
    $(".pBox").css("border-color","#ccc");
    var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $parent
    .css("border-color","#cc0000");
    .animate({
        height: ($parent.height() + (0.1 * $parent.height()))
    });
});
```